Off Canvas Nav Double Click to Open
Using Blazor server, with Bootstrap. Currently, if I navigate from the home page and try to open the off canvas nav, I must click twice. The first click seems to make it active, the second actually opens it. I'd like it to just... open the first time.
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="nav-section">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNav" aria-controls="offcanvasNav">
            <i class="bi bi-list"></i>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img class="logo" src="/LOGO.png" alt="logo stacked" />
        </a>
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <Breadcrumbs/>
        </div>
    </div>

 <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNav" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavLabel">
     <div class="offcanvas-header">
         <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavLabel">Application</h5>
         <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
     </div>
</div>

I tried adding @rendermode Interactive Server, which fixes the issue, but introduces two issues.

The menu doesn't close upon new page load.
It messes up my 'active link' which is done like so:

   <li class="admin-dropdown">
       <a class="admin-item dropdown-item @(IsActiveRoute("/Admin/Courses"))" href="/Admin/Courses">
           Edit Courses
           <i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i>
       </a>
   </li>

@code {
    private string GetRelativePath()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(NavManager.Uri);
        var relativePath = uri.AbsolutePath;
        return relativePath;
    }

    private bool IsActiveRoute(string route)
    {
        return GetRelativePath() == route;
    }
}```



Your question doesn't make clear what type of project you have or where interactivity is set, but in order to have an off-canvas control toggle on and off you need to enable interactivity.
Building a Minimal Reproducible Example from the provided code isn't simple, so here's a demo page and a OffCanvasControl component that you can adapt to fit your requirements.
First the off canvas functionality built into a component:
@if (this.Show)
{

    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="visibility:visible">
        <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <h5 id="offcanvasRightLabel">@((MarkupString)(Title ?? "Off Canvas") )</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" @onclick="this.Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
            @this.ChildContent
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-backdrop fade show offcanvas-backdrop" style="z-index: 1040;" @onclick="this.Close">
    </div>

}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool Show { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> ShowChanged { get; set; }

    private void Close()
    {
        this.ShowChanged.InvokeAsync(false);
    }
}

It uses two way binding to show and hide the content.
And a demo page:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.Show">Toggle right offcanvas</button>

<OffCanvasControl @bind-Show="_offCanvasOpen" Title="Off Canvas Demo">
    Hello ....
</OffCanvasControl>

@code {
    private bool _offCanvasOpen;

    private void Show()
    {
        _offCanvasOpen = true;
        // This is a UI event so this component will render at this point
         // As the OffCanvasControl bind Value has changed 
         // the Renderer will call `SetParametersAsync` on OffCanvasControl
        // which will render that component
    }
}


Sorry, I'm using the Bootstrap off-canvas. The application uses server-side interactivity, but if I add that directly to the nav (using @rendermode InteractiveServer), it causes other issues (not closing on a new page, for one). Otherwise, not setting an rendermode, it works fine, except for the double click of the hamburger icon to open it.

NP, though it isn't strictly Blazor Server. In SSR mode, you relying on the full Bootstrap JS implementation to do the work in the browser.

Judging from the reproduced behavior locally that all correct when refresh page or first start the app, but have to click more than once after nevigating to other component, it is very likely the issue of how Blazor page rendered, DOM modifed or state initializing.
So I tested with a workaround to handle this, and it worked.
<body>
    <Routes  />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    ...
    ...
    <script>
        function initializeOffcanvas() {
            const offcanvasElement = document.getElementById('offcanvasNav');
            if (offcanvasElement) {
                let offcanvasInstance = bootstrap.Offcanvas.getInstance(offcanvasElement);
                if (!offcanvasInstance) {
                    offcanvasInstance = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(offcanvasElement);
                }
            }
        }

        function hideOffcanvas() {
            const offcanvasElement = document.getElementById('offcanvasNav');
            if (offcanvasElement) {
                const offcanvasInstance = bootstrap.Offcanvas.getInstance(offcanvasElement);
                if (offcanvasInstance && offcanvasElement.classList.contains('show')) {
                    offcanvasInstance.hide();
                }
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            initializeOffcanvas();

            const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a.nav-link');
            navLinks.forEach(link => {
                link.addEventListener('click', hideOffcanvas);
            });

            document.addEventListener('blazor:afterRender', initializeOffcanvas);
        });
    </script>
</body>

It ensures the state is initialized every time loaded.
